# Recursive Bulk Edit in Linux

Tags: linux, recursion, editor, bulk

I am trying to change certain lines in multiple files (scattered in subfolders) without having to edit each file one by one. I was given by Chas. the following

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's{[^/]Css/Template.css}{/Css/Template.css}' *
```

and it worked like a charm but was wondering if this command or similar can be done recursively in one shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi.bak -e 's{[^/]Css/Template.css}{/Css/Template.css}' '{}' '+'
```

This will apply it to all files in the current directory and all subdirectories. It will not follow symlinks. You might want to narrow the scope of the find with a -name directive as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I thought adding -r would do it recursively, heh. Now time to remove those bak files ...

Comment: You can use find again to easily get rid of those .bak files too :)

Comment: *slap in the head* how embarrassing ... look away